# Enthusiastic Expression (in Blue)

Tags: riddle, knowledge, rhyme, poetry

Pardon the bad poetry, but who am I thinking of?

> Uncle Sam took a journey to France,
> Sky-high wisps for to move with his feet,
> And to feel a particular emotion,
> A feeling so down-low and sweet.
>
> He'd have liked to go buy up his favorite,
> But, alas, there were none in the stack.
> There was someone who *did* get to buy it,
> But disliked it, and gave it right back.
>
> He cut a short story in quarters,
> Then daydreamed of young golden cows,
> But that night, he was up without slumber,
> Thinking thoughts while he furrowed his brows.

(Of course, I came up with this myself)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are thinking of:

> the American pianist and composer, [George Gershwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Gershwin) (1898-1937).
>
>  This can be worked out by noting that many of the lines clue **the titles of some of his most famous works**, all of which can be found on the album [*Gershwin Plays Gershwin: The Piano Rolls*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershwin_Plays_Gershwin:_The_Piano_Rolls), a compilation released in 1993. In fact, the title is a big reference to one of his most famous pieces of all, *[Rhapsody in Blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhapsody_in_Blue)*, which is also on the compilation album.

*Uncle Sam took a journey to France,*

> *[An American in Paris](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoEYxeYHCfI)*

*Sky-high wisps for to move with his feet,*

> [*Kickin' the Clouds Away*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlt2h0h5nBg)

*And to feel a particular emotion,*

> [*That Certain Feeling*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_p8xKT0aZ80)

*A feeling so down-low and sweet.*

> [*Sweet and Lowdown*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqCn_NjV7gI)

*He'd have liked to go buy up his favorite,*
*But, alas, there were none in the stack.*
*There was someone who did get to buy it,*
*But disliked it, and gave it right back.*

> This whole paragraph is a reference to [*When You Want 'Em You Can't Get 'Em, When You've Got 'Em, You Don't Want 'Em*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHC3j3GKNr4)

*He cut a short story in quarters,*

> [*Novelette in Fourths*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfldvUyu8b8)

*Then daydreamed of young golden cows,*

> [*Idle Dreams*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyrVxxzWn1w) - since 'idle' sounds like 'idol', with a reference to the 'golden calf' from the [Biblical account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_calf) in Exodus.

*But that night, he was up without slumber,*
*Thinking thoughts while he furrowed his brows.*

> [*On My Mind the Whole Night Long*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1G9U0kZKak). This might also feasibly reference *Sleepless Night* - an unpublished work listed on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compositions_by_George_Gershwin).

Comment: one question- how, just how?

Comment: @JLee Ha! I spotted the title connection. Then google and a YouTube rabbithole brought up the goods...

Comment: Well done again! You got everything exactly right!